# Unable to install python packages from remote repo

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

I am trying to download deendencies from artifactory in the fllowing way

requirements.txt

```
--index-url  https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-repos
django-rss-plugin==0.0.9
nltk==3.0.1
```

And then running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This results in the follwoing error

```
Collecting django-rss-plugin==0.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-rss-plugin==0.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-rss-plugin==0.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
```

This is true for any dependency. I am using the version 9.0.1 for pip.Also https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-repos is the virtual repository that proxies the remote repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the index in your command and remove from the file:

```
pip install -r requirement.txt -i https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-repos
```

File:

```
django-rss-plugin==0.0.9
nltk==3.0.1
```

**EDIT**

The error is from the index URL itself.

Comment: that gives me "You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
"

Comment: which error ? can you copy paste the command and the error to your question ?

Comment: Perfect! I think the link used in your index URL doesn't work. Opening it returns an error, can you validate it ?

Comment: Thanks!!!! That was the issue, since I am trying to get this from the remote repo I had to append it with /simple

Comment: I saw it from the start but I said it can be this easy :) Good for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133471/discussion-between-saksow-and-user-mda).